# SVGPan - anyone figure out ios touch event support?

Tags: ios, touch, jquery-svg

I've been working with SVGPan (http://code.google.com/p/svgpan/) and I have generally found it fantastic (so thanks to all involved!).

Just wondering, did anyone ever add functionality to support ios devices (I'm mainly interested in the i-pad at the moment!)? I've been trying to work with some changes myself but I haven't got past being able to pan / drag more than one svg element at a time e.g. a rect / circle. I can't get it to work with a group of svg elements at once based on the various touch events. Best thing I've found is this: http://techblog.floorplanner.com/post/20528546052/interactive-svg-on-the-ipad.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can inspect the javascript (not jquery) I wrote for the curve widget (down at the bottom (like 70% down)) in [this blog post](http://ronnqvi.st/thinking-like-a-bzier-path/) if that is of any help to you. You can only touch one element at a time though but a few different SVG elements are changed when you drag it. If it looks like something that would be helpful I could try and explain the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try hammer.js (http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/) and there is a demo you can try with your ios browser: http://riagora.com/mobile/hammer/